# Add new tasks when the number of active jobs becomes less than N

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize some very time-consuming tasks on a certain number of cores. My goal is to exploit the server resources as much as possible. The total number of CPUs is 20, but the number of tasks to do is much more (say, 100).

Each task runs for a different time, so the code below leaves an opportunity for a certain number of cores to idle without work.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp


def some_task(*args):
    # Something happening here
    pass


cpu_count = mp.cpu_count()
p = mp.Pool(cpu_count)

n_thread = 1
for something in somethings:

    p.apply_async(some_task, args=(something, ))

    if n_thread == cpu_count:
        p.close()
        p.join()
        p = mp.Pool(cpu_count)
        n_thread = 1
        continue
    n_thread += 1

p.close()
if n_thread != 1:
    p.join()
```

How to program the code that will start new tasks when the number of active jobs becomes less than the number of CPUs?

Comment: If `multiprocessing` is on the table, you might look at using one of the [Queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) (essentially what you're implementing by hand here). Also see [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#module-queue)

Comment: Well that's exactly what `Pool` together with `apply_async` will do. Just submit as many tasks as you want. It will assign them to workers as they become free. You can leave out that complete `if` branch.

Comment: Thank you all! I just realized that it works exactly as @a_guest wrote.